# Open sharepoint word file in users desktop app by clicking on direct hyperlink to word document

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word

In our web application, we have direct link to word document in SharePoint site. So when user clicks on the hyperlink, I would like to open that in users local desktop word application. But I am unable to achieve it.
I have tried other work arounds like, when user clicks on the document in the sharepoint site, able to open in word desktop app. But it is still two clicks for user to reach the word desktop app.

Is there any way if we pass any parameters in the url saying open in local desktop app?

Thanks

Comment: This is generally a user option. I am unsure whether this would be more appropriately posted in Super User. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word   What questions can I ask about here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code to open the desktop app directly in users machine. It will ask for confirmation though before opening the document in local.

ms-word:ofe|u|https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/xxx/xx.docx